# Angular 2 use tag Div as selector for component

Tags: html, angular, tags

I need to use as name selector (div) for my Childcomponent
the probleme is in my parentComponent I have many tags (DIV)
SO I need a trick to identify my div (of childComponent)
(because I need to do some drag&drop on div when I use another name (default) I cant use it)

```
@Component({
    selector: 'div',
    template: `<div  [innerHTML]="content"></div>`,

})
export class ChildComponent {
    @Input() content:string='';
    }
```

and in view html of my parent I put this

```
<div [content]="value">
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the question but you could add the `content` attribute to the selector:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'div[content]',
    template: `<div  [innerHTML]="content"></div>`,

})
export class ChildComponent {
    @Input() content:string='';
}
```

and then use it like

```
<div [content]="value">
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/wS1t10CxE0VwJthoVP7U?p=preview)

Comment: I would have obviously a lot of tag div in my html page
I need to identify the tag div that I bring from ChildComponent
in order that this div will have a special display
I need the div from ChildComponent have a  wysiwyg
and other div remain normal

Comment: Sorry, I don't get the point of your comment. The `ChildComponent` is only applied to elements that have `content` attribute. What does not work as expected with my proposed solution. What is the desired behavior?

Comment: I just saw the plunker thanks it works 
thank you very much ^^